# How to do nested loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops

I would like to do nested loop in my programming. However, this code did not meet my expectation.

```
X=[0,1,1,1,0]

length=len(X)
for i,val in enumerate(X):
    a=0
    count=0
    while (count<length):
        a=15+a
        print (a)
        HWPQ=np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(4*math.radians(a)), 
        math.sin(4*math.radians(a)), 0], [0, math.sin(4 * math.radians(a)), - 
        math.cos(4 * math.radians(a)), 0], [0, 0, 0, -1]])
        result=HWPQ*val
        print (result)
        count=count +1
    print ("\n")
```

Supposedly, in this program, I would like to update the value of `a` for each element using the loop. For example:

```
X=0 for a=0
X=1 for a=15
X=1 for a=30
X=1 for a=45
X=0 for a=60
```

The result should be, as I calculated it manually:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 1.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.8660254 -0.5        0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.        -1.       ]]
[[ 1.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.        -0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.8660254  0.5        0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.        -1.       ]]
[[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00]]
 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: What's `X` used in this code? Seems useless? `a` just a arithmetic progression, ignore any value of `X`

Comment: Is that last one correct? you're multiplying your matrix by `val`, which is 0, so the whole matrix would be `0`s.

Comment: @ i alarmed alien. You are correct. I have updated the last output.

Comment: @atline. The value of `X` is represented as list of bit 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes, I missed it, it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a load of unnecessary variables in your code, like `count`, `X`, and `i`. Removing them and using a standard `for` loop, you get:

```
X=[0,1,1,1,0]
a=0
for val in X:
    print (a)
    HWPQ=np.matrix([
        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, math.cos(4*math.radians(a)), math.sin(4*math.radians(a)), 0], 
        [0, math.sin(4 * math.radians(a)), - math.cos(4 * math.radians(a)), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, -1]])
    result=HWPQ*val
    print (result)
    a=15+a
    print ("\n")
```

which creates the output that you want.

```
0
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]


15
[[ 1.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.8660254 -0.5        0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.        -1.       ]]


30
[[ 1.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.        -0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.8660254  0.5        0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.        -1.       ]]


45
[[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00]]


60
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```